# Reload a script via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using [TableSorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to order the content of my table.
The table's content can be modified with ajax and when it happens the plugin doesn't register the dom' update, so the sort fail.

How can I reload the script, so it "sees" the new DOM?

Comment: I doubt that reloading the script will do anything. It already modified the DOM. Are you following the guides from the example? tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: Thank you very much.
I had looked over and over for a similar solution in the documentation of the script, but I had absolutely not noticed the solution that you posted.